# Largest possible open circle inside an open circle?

Tags: circles

When you construct the largest possible open circle within another open circle, can the radii of both circles be equal to each other? Or does the inner circle need to have a radius strictly < the larger one (when we write the actual inequality)?

Comment: The two radii are the same if and only if the two centres are the same. Otherwise, the radius of the contained disk is strictly smaller than the radius of the containing disk.

Comment: If by open circle you mean a set of the form $|x|<R$, then the largest open circle contained within an open circle is itself.

Comment: There is no largest open ball properly contained inside another open ball (at least in context of metric spaces).

Comment: In certain metric spaces it is possible that $B(x,r_1)\subseteq B(y,r_2)$ can hold even in some cases where $r_1>r_2$.